# Ubuntu getting struck on purple screen

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu 18.04. After finishing installation and restarting system, Ubuntu is getting struck on purple screen and not proceeding further

Comment: Usually when this happens some daemon is failing to start. Try booting and holding SHIFT key, the GRUB interface should pop up. Press "e" key to edit the default entry and remove "quiet splash". In this way during the boot you'll be able to see logs of what's happening and eventually tell us where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I, unfortunately, do not have enough reputation to comment, so I am saying this in an answer. Have you tried pressing one of the "function" keys? (f1, f2, f3, etc.) This should bring up the boot output. you can then see if there is anything there to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Windows 7 came out while systems still used legacy bios.  As such there may be problems if the installer is confused about how to install the boot loader.

My laptop is uefi capable but has windows 7 installed (upgraded to windows 10) and thus an MBR config on the drive.  Ubuntu was installed legacy bios mode to support dual booting and keep windows available.

The earlier suggestion about going into the bios and looking may give you a clue.  Ubuntu can boot on either, but some of the bios settings may leave the os to determine which mode ( UEFI or BIOS ) to use for booting and I have seen systems hang unless the setting within the bios actually provided a fixed boot mode setting.  If the os boot loader is not installed properly (uefi requires an efi partition, legacy bios does not.  Also the boot sector is sized differently.) it will hang when it hits the error.

In my experience the installer is not confused if there is already an os on the drive as it can see the boot mode.  With no os to look it may try to install in uefi mode while the drive is partitioned as MBR mode.  This could cause the hang.
I have had it happen, and changing the bios setting fixed it for me.